# 13.04 installer crashes

Tags: installation, 13.04

the installer crashes after codec selection step. if wifi is enabled then is crashes after the wifi selection step. clicking next in the above steps show a dialog box with no readable text, only some question marks. any ideas? FYI: i have 3 hard drives in my system.

Comment: Looks like a known problem (I faced similar issues during 12.10). Before you start installation from LiveDVD/LiveUSB, make sure you're not connected to any network, not even physically (detach Ethernet cable from your computer, turn off Wifi) and then start installation and see if it goes well.

Comment: u can disconnect all the drives except one. and the problem goes away. it is definitely a careless and stupid bug with the installer or how it handles parted. not a network problem.

Answer (score 1):

Was having a similar issue (hang after network installation completed and hostname provided).  Disconnecting the second hard drive fixed it.